# how can i use regular Expression for selecting some string from long string

Tags: c#, regex, string, logging

Here is one line of the string:

```
[14/Sep/2014 14:34:25] Recv: Queue-ID: 54157d41-00000000, Service: SMTP, From: <bedele.document@hawkifc.com>, To: <bedele.document@hawkifc.com>, Size: 626, Sender-Host: 172.27.9.12, Subject: Microsoft Outlook Test Message
```

how can I find the email address which is next the substring **From: <** and **To: <**

looking forward for you quick help
thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1):

With something like:

```
string str = "[14/Sep/2014 14:34:25] Recv: Queue-ID: 54157d41-00000000, Service: SMTP, From: Foo, To: Baz, Size: 626, Sender-Host: 172.27.9.12, Subject: Microsoft Outlook Test Message";

var rx = new Regex(@"(?:(?:, From: )(?<From>[^,]*)|(?:, To: )(?<To>[^,]*)|(?:.))*");
var match = rx.Match(str);
bool success = match.Success;
string from = match.Groups["From"].Value;
string to = match.Groups["To"].Value;
```

This

```
(?:(?:, From: )(?<From>[^,]*)|(?:, To: )(?<To>[^,]*)|.)*
```

means something like:

- (character by character) check if we are at a `, From:`: if yes, put what is after up to the first `,` (`[^,]*`) in the *From* match
- or check if we are at a `, To:`: if yes, put what is after up to the first `,` (`[^,]*`) in the *To* match
- or consume a single character `.`
- Then repeat until the end of the string (`*`)